Turning off the high side power MOSFET without disrupting circuit functionality
I have a voltage clamp circuit like this. I want to turn the power MOSFET on and off with the MCU, but I don't want the clamp functionality of the circuit to be damaged. What are your suggestions in this case?


"don't want the clamp functionality of the circuit to be damaged" By clamp, do you mean D7?

yes, the circuit simply protects the output against surge voltage and clamps it. I want to turn the p channel enhancement type mosfet on and off directly with the mcu without disrupting the clamping feature.

It's a very strange place to clamp it, unless it tries to analog-ly raise Q1 base voltage in order to turn off your P-MOSFET. What's your load, and what's the expected source of surge voltage?

Which has functional priority?

what specs must be met?

What about pulling the base of Q1 down to GND with a BJT to turn it off?

As Jens said, a switch to Q1B to gnd will shut-off FET safely with 6 V max and appears as less than a 1mA load with a threshold of 2~3V.
Any NPN open collector or Nch drain will work as a on/off switch to Vb & gnd.
There are 3 clamp Zeners with curious functions;

D? = 6.2 V  The reference voltage for Q1b that controls  V(Q1e) = 6.2-0.6 = 5.6 V thus Ic~Ie = 5.6/10k and R1 = 20k  This seems to the add offset to the 110V limiter.
D3 = 12  V, limits Vgs on FET but since the 20k current comes from the 10k emitter , the voltage will never rise to 12V before something else fries. Thus D3 is redundant with Vgs being limited by (D?-Vbe)*R1/R11
D7 = 110 V is OVP limiter to about Vout = Ve(=5.6) + Vz (=110V)
Power dissipation in the FET switch will then rise with the load current.

SInce D? is the priority clamp Zener
